GEOPANDAS: Skipping field attribute_name: invalid type (1, 0)
Iam trying to read .gml file in python via GeoPandas using gpd.read_file with next code:
gdf = gpd.read_file(r'path_to_file/gml-file_neme.gml', driver='GML')
but some columns GeoPandas cant read and I got warning message: Skipping field attribute_name: invalid type (1, 0) for every column which could not be read. Can someone give me some advise how to fix reading .gml file. Thank you
<wfs:FeatureCollection xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs">
    <gml:featureMember xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
        <feature:features xmlns:feature="http://mapserver.gis.umn.edu/mapserver">
            <feature:geometry>
                <gml:Polygon>
                    <gml:outerBoundaryIs>
                        <gml:LinearRing>
                            <gml:coordinates>290580.239986,4974075.740001541 290589.06000364,4974077.980006021 290589.06000364,4974073.079996221 290582.19998992,4974072.939995941 290580.239986,4974075.740001541</gml:coordinates>
                        </gml:LinearRing>
                    </gml:outerBoundaryIs>
                </gml:Polygon>
            </feature:geometry>
            <feature:column_1><![CDATA[String]]></feature:column_1>
            <feature:column_2><![CDATA[Some string 2]]></feature:column_2>
            <feature:column_3><![CDATA[G]]></feature:column_3>
            <feature:column_4><![CDATA[Some string]]></feature:column_4>
            <feature:column_5><![CDATA[String]]></feature:column_5>
            <feature:column_6><![CDATA[String-202300003]]></feature:column_6>
            <feature:column_7><![CDATA[123456789]]></feature:column_7>
            <feature:column_8><![CDATA[123456789]]></feature:column_8>
            <feature:column_9><![CDATA[G]]></feature:column_9>
            <feature:column_10><![CDATA[Some string]]></feature:column_10>
            <feature:column_11><![CDATA[Some string]]></feature:column_11>
            <feature:column_12><![CDATA[Some string]]></feature:column_12>
            <feature:column_13>
                <feature:column_13a>
                    <feature:column_13aa><![CDATA[191]]></feature:column_13aa>
                    <feature:column_13ab><![CDATA[String]]></feature:column_13ab>
                    <feature:column_13ac><![CDATA[2]]></feature:column_13ac>
                    <feature:column_13ad><![CDATA[Some string]]></feature:column_13ad>
                    <feature:column_13ae><![CDATA[02488]]></feature:column_13ae>
                    <feature:column_13af><![CDATA[String]]></feature:column_13af>
                    <feature:column_13ag><![CDATA[017051]]></feature:column_13ag>
                    <feature:column_13ah><![CDATA[Some string]]></feature:column_13ah>
                    <feature:column_13ai><![CDATA[0170510001]]></feature:column_13ai>
                    <feature:column_13aj><![CDATA[Some string]]></feature:column_13aj>
                    <feature:column_13ak><![CDATA[20]]></feature:column_13ak>
                </feature:column_13a>
            </feature:column_13>
            <feature:column_14>
                <feature:column_14a>
                    <feature:column_14aa><![CDATA[324256]]></feature:column_14aa>
                    <feature:column_14ab><![CDATA[String]]></feature:column_14ab>
                    <feature:column_14ac><![CDATA[422]]></feature:column_14ac>
                </feature:column_14a>
                <feature:column_14a>
                    <feature:column_14aa><![CDATA[324256]]></feature:column_14aa>
                    <feature:column_14ab><![CDATA[String]]></feature:column_14ab>
                    <feature:column_14ac><![CDATA[422]]></feature:column_14ac>
                </feature:column_14a>
                <feature:column_14a>
                    <feature:column_14aa><![CDATA[324256]]></feature:column_14aa>
                    <feature:column_14ab><![CDATA[String]]></feature:column_14ab>
                    <feature:column_14ac><![CDATA[422]]></feature:column_14ac>
                </feature:column_14a>
                <feature:column_14a>
                    <feature:column_14aa><![CDATA[324256]]></feature:column_14aa>
                    <feature:column_14ab><![CDATA[String]]></feature:column_14ab>
                    <feature:column_14ac><![CDATA[422]]></feature:column_14ac>
                </feature:column_14a>
                <feature:column_14a>
                    <feature:column_14aa><![CDATA[324256]]></feature:column_14aa>
                    <feature:column_14ab><![CDATA[String]]></feature:column_14ab>
                    <feature:column_14ac><![CDATA[422]]></feature:column_14ac>
                </feature:column_14a>
                <feature:column_14a>
                    <feature:column_14aa><![CDATA[324256]]></feature:column_14aa>
                    <feature:column_14ab><![CDATA[String]]></feature:column_14ab>
                    <feature:column_14ac><![CDATA[422]]></feature:column_14ac>
                </feature:column_14a>
                <feature:column_14a>
                    <feature:column_14aa><![CDATA[324256]]></feature:column_14aa>
                    <feature:column_14ab><![CDATA[String]]></feature:column_14ab>
                    <feature:column_14ac><![CDATA[422]]></feature:column_14ac>
                </feature:column_14a>
                <feature:column_14a>
                    <feature:column_14aa><![CDATA[324256]]></feature:column_14aa>
                    <feature:column_14ab><![CDATA[String]]></feature:column_14ab>
                    <feature:column_14ac><![CDATA[422]]></feature:column_14ac>
                </feature:column_14a>
                <feature:column_14a>
                    <feature:column_14aa><![CDATA[324256]]></feature:column_14aa>
                    <feature:column_14ab><![CDATA[String]]></feature:column_14ab>
                    <feature:column_14ac><![CDATA[422]]></feature:column_14ac>
                </feature:column_14a>
                <feature:column_14a>
                    <feature:column_14aa><![CDATA[324256]]></feature:column_14aa>
                    <feature:column_14ab><![CDATA[String]]></feature:column_14ab>
                    <feature:column_14ac><![CDATA[422]]></feature:column_14ac>
                </feature:column_14a>
                <feature:column_14a>
                    <feature:column_14aa><![CDATA[324256]]></feature:column_14aa>
                    <feature:column_14ab><![CDATA[String]]></feature:column_14ab>
                    <feature:column_14ac><![CDATA[422]]></feature:column_14ac>
                </feature:column_14a>
                <feature:column_14a>
                    <feature:column_14aa><![CDATA[324256]]></feature:column_14aa>
                    <feature:column_14ab><![CDATA[String]]></feature:column_14ab>
                    <feature:column_14ac><![CDATA[422]]></feature:column_14ac>
                </feature:column_14a>
                <feature:column_14a>
                    <feature:column_14aa><![CDATA[324256]]></feature:column_14aa>
                    <feature:column_14ab><![CDATA[String]]></feature:column_14ab>
                    <feature:column_14ac><![CDATA[422]]></feature:column_14ac>
                </feature:column_14a>
                <feature:column_14a>
                    <feature:column_14aa><![CDATA[324256]]></feature:column_14aa>
                    <feature:column_14ab><![CDATA[String]]></feature:column_14ab>
                    <feature:column_14ac><![CDATA[422]]></feature:column_14ac>
                </feature:column_14a>
                <feature:column_14a>
                    <feature:column_14aa><![CDATA[324256]]></feature:column_14aa>
                    <feature:column_14ab><![CDATA[String]]></feature:column_14ab>
                    <feature:column_14ac><![CDATA[422]]></feature:column_14ac>
                </feature:column_14a>
                <feature:column_14a>
                    <feature:column_14aa><![CDATA[324256]]></feature:column_14aa>
                    <feature:column_14ab><![CDATA[String]]></feature:column_14ab>
                    <feature:column_14ac><![CDATA[422]]></feature:column_14ac>
                </feature:column_14a>
                <feature:column_14a>
                    <feature:column_14aa><![CDATA[324256]]></feature:column_14aa>
                    <feature:column_14ab><![CDATA[String]]></feature:column_14ab>
                    <feature:column_14ac><![CDATA[422]]></feature:column_14ac>
                </feature:column_14a>
                <feature:column_14a>
                    <feature:column_14aa><![CDATA[324256]]></feature:column_14aa>
                    <feature:column_14ab><![CDATA[String]]></feature:column_14ab>
                    <feature:column_14ac><![CDATA[422]]></feature:column_14ac>
                </feature:column_14a>
                <feature:column_14a>
                    <feature:column_14aa><![CDATA[324256]]></feature:column_14aa>
                    <feature:column_14ab><![CDATA[String]]></feature:column_14ab>
                    <feature:column_14ac><![CDATA[422]]></feature:column_14ac>
                </feature:column_14a>
                <feature:column_14a>
                    <feature:column_14aa><![CDATA[324256]]></feature:column_14aa>
                    <feature:column_14ab><![CDATA[String]]></feature:column_14ab>
                    <feature:column_14ac><![CDATA[422]]></feature:column_14ac>
                </feature:column_14a>
                <feature:column_14a>
                    <feature:column_14aa><![CDATA[324256]]></feature:column_14aa>
                    <feature:column_14ab><![CDATA[String]]></feature:column_14ab>
                    <feature:column_14ac><![CDATA[422]]></feature:column_14ac>
                </feature:column_14a>
                <feature:column_14a>
                    <feature:column_14aa><![CDATA[324256]]></feature:column_14aa>
                    <feature:column_14ab><![CDATA[String]]></feature:column_14ab>
                    <feature:column_14ac><![CDATA[422]]></feature:column_14ac>
                </feature:column_14a>
                <feature:column_14a>
                    <feature:column_14aa><![CDATA[324256]]></feature:column_14aa>
                    <feature:column_14ab><![CDATA[String]]></feature:column_14ab>
                    <feature:column_14ac><![CDATA[422]]></feature:column_14ac>
                </feature:column_14a>
                <feature:column_14a>
                    <feature:column_14aa><![CDATA[324256]]></feature:column_14aa>
                    <feature:column_14ab><![CDATA[String]]></feature:column_14ab>
                    <feature:column_14ac><![CDATA[422]]></feature:column_14ac>
                </feature:column_14a>
                <feature:column_14a>
                    <feature:column_14aa><![CDATA[324256]]></feature:column_14aa>
                    <feature:column_14ab><![CDATA[String]]></feature:column_14ab>
                    <feature:column_14ac><![CDATA[422]]></feature:column_14ac>
                </feature:column_14a>
                <feature:column_14a>
                    <feature:column_14aa><![CDATA[324256]]></feature:column_14aa>
                    <feature:column_14ab><![CDATA[String]]></feature:column_14ab>
                    <feature:column_14ac><![CDATA[422]]></feature:column_14ac>
                </feature:column_14a>
                <feature:column_14a>
                    <feature:column_14aa><![CDATA[324256]]></feature:column_14aa>
                    <feature:column_14ab><![CDATA[String]]></feature:column_14ab>
                    <feature:column_14ac><![CDATA[422]]></feature:column_14ac>
                </feature:column_14a>
                <feature:column_14a>
                    <feature:column_14aa><![CDATA[324256]]></feature:column_14aa>
                    <feature:column_14ab><![CDATA[String]]></feature:column_14ab>
                    <feature:column_14ac><![CDATA[422]]></feature:column_14ac>
                </feature:column_14a>
                <feature:column_14a>
                    <feature:column_14aa><![CDATA[324256]]></feature:column_14aa>
                    <feature:column_14ab><![CDATA[String]]></feature:column_14ab>
                    <feature:column_14ac><![CDATA[422]]></feature:column_14ac>
                </feature:column_14a>
                <feature:column_14a>
                    <feature:column_14aa><![CDATA[324256]]></feature:column_14aa>
                    <feature:column_14ab><![CDATA[String]]></feature:column_14ab>
                    <feature:column_14ac><![CDATA[422]]></feature:column_14ac>
                </feature:column_14a>
                <feature:column_14a>
                    <feature:column_14aa><![CDATA[324256]]></feature:column_14aa>
                    <feature:column_14ab><![CDATA[String]]></feature:column_14ab>
                    <feature:column_14ac><![CDATA[422]]></feature:column_14ac>
                </feature:column_14a>
                <feature:column_14a>
                    <feature:column_14aa><![CDATA[324256]]></feature:column_14aa>
                    <feature:column_14ab><![CDATA[String]]></feature:column_14ab>
                    <feature:column_14ac><![CDATA[422]]></feature:column_14ac>
                </feature:column_14a>
                <feature:column_14a>
                    <feature:column_14aa><![CDATA[324256]]></feature:column_14aa>
                    <feature:column_14ab><![CDATA[String]]></feature:column_14ab>
                    <feature:column_14ac><![CDATA[422]]></feature:column_14ac>
                </feature:column_14a>
                <feature:column_14a>
                    <feature:column_14aa><![CDATA[324256]]></feature:column_14aa>
                    <feature:column_14ab><![CDATA[String]]></feature:column_14ab>
                    <feature:column_14ac><![CDATA[422]]></feature:column_14ac>
                </feature:column_14a>
                <feature:column_14a>
                    <feature:column_14aa><![CDATA[324256]]></feature:column_14aa>
                    <feature:column_14ab><![CDATA[String]]></feature:column_14ab>
                    <feature:column_14ac><![CDATA[422]]></feature:column_14ac>
                </feature:column_14a>
            </feature:column_14>
        </feature:features>
    </gml:featureMember>
</wfs:FeatureCollection>

WARNING  Skipping field column_13aa: invalid type (1, 0)
WARNING  Skipping field column_13ak: invalid type (1, 0)
WARNING  Skipping field column_14aa: invalid type (1, 0)
WARNING  Skipping field column_14ac: invalid type (1, 0)

Please share a (part of) the gml file in question...

What are the valid types defined for feature:column_*  elements in your custom namespace?

I've never used gml, but I only get the error for column_14aa, column_14ab and column_14ac. When looking at the file, those columns are repeated > 10 times, maybe that's the problem?
